# Downloading ArcGIS Bump Map Tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5

I am interested to download ESRI Bump Map Tools for ArcGIS referred in the below link,

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/01/21/introducing-the-arcgis-bump-map-tools/

I have searched for these tools but cant find the working link to download and utilize these tools in ArcGIS 10.5.

If these tools are compatible with ArcGIS 10.5, where can I download them?

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a seven and a half year old blog post, not a product plan.

Comment: Yes, revival of these tools is still welcomed

Comment: That was three computer generations ago. People move on, do different things. Just because you want it ported to modern software doesn't mean there is is anyone available (or inclined, or funded) to do so. This looks like at least three months of development.  Are you prepared to pay $150k-$250k for someone to revive them?

Comment: Looking at the screen shots from the other answers I would say a few days to port it into modern toolboxes. If it was moved all into python toolboxes then it may take a bit longer. But not months! The issue here is simply getting hold of it and the logic encapsulated by the code developed 7 years ago would still be valid today. A couple of years ago when ArcScripts was alive I remember porting someones AML into ArcObjects, worked a treat. I hope someone from ESRI digs it out and places it up on their code sharing website where it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great news everyone, the download link on the blog page has been reinstated!

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/01/21/introducing-the-arcgis-bump-map-tools/

Tested on ArcMap 10.5 and it worked a treat.

Comment: Great news. At last, these incredible tools are ready to be explored and experimented.

Answer (score 3):

Not easy task as it doesn't seem available on the net anymore. Below some info gathered here on those tools if you can't find them anymore.

If **Rajinder Nag**i is not available, you can try reaching out also : **Jeffery S. Nighbert**, Senior Technical Specialist for GIS, Bureau of Land Management Oregon (Ref. https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/09/13/bump-mapping-presentation-at-esri-uc-2010/)

**EDIT** : If found extra references by looking for : "Bump Mapping Techniques for Cartographers" which led to **"Bump Mapping" and Spatial Analyst - Semantic Scholar"** with a lot a formulae to do it : https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f396/b533564b925d958e76aa6b05de00ad9e5036.pdf

---

The author says :

> Bump mapping is done by first **creating a random point pattern**, using
>   that pattern to **create bumps as a raster surface**, **adding the bumped
>   surface to the underlying DEM**, **hillshading** the DEM, and then
>   **symbolizing** the results.

***Ref. : https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/01/25/symbolizing-the-bump-map/***

---

**EDIT**
I found a tutorial from M. Nighbert in my archives. There might be some bits missing, but it can help rebuilding the tool maybe :

**About bump mapping**

If you want to add realism to your map, try to find ways to modulate the tones of your features.  For vegetation, one way to do this is using a technique called bump mapping, which produces an effect that looks like tree tops in vegetated areas.  We’ll show you how this can be done using a methodology that Jeff Nighbert of the Oregon BLM developed for ArcGIS.

This is essentially done in four steps:

1. create the random pattern for the density of the trees or other vegetation,
2. modify it to look like coniferous, deciduous or other land cover,
3. apply it to the appropriate land cover areas, and
4. symbolize it.

In addition, you can modify the bump mapping method to make the tree tops look more deciduous, more coniferous or even like shrub or grassland.

The two layers you need for input are your digital elevation model and a raster of the vegetation.  You will also create a layer for the random pattern for the vegetation.

**Create a bump map**

1. In Spatial Analyst, you will use the Raster Calculator.  You want to enter this formula (note that you can cut and paste this):

   `(eucdistance(con( ($$rowmap mod int(normal() * 5 + 10) eq 0) and ($$colmap mod int(normal() * 5 + 10) eq 0),255),#,#,60,#)) * (-20 / 10) + 120`.
2. Copy the formula in and click OK to start the calculation.
   What this does is to create a random pattern that is spaced about 20 cells by 20 cells and it also creates coned shaped features around the randomly located points.  The expression also sets the height of the cones to 120 feet.
3. Turn on the Pattern layer so we can see the results.  If you zoom in to your Pattern bookmark, you can see that the cells look like randomly placed trees with tops that area a bit cone-like.
4. Note the values in the Table of Contents.  The top of each tree is 120 ft high and the bottom is 0.  120 is a pretty normal height for coniferous trees in the Pacific Northwest.  You should modify the values to be similar to the types of vegetation in your mapped area.
5. Now you want to add these values to your DEM.  To do this, you also need a raster layer of tree cover within the park boundary where trees = 1 and no trees = null.  Turn on your park_trees layer so you can see the layer we created with these values.
6. Then you need to go back into the Spatial Analyst Raster Calculator so you can enter the next formula you need:

`hillshade(con(isnull([park trees]),[bathy_dem_ft],[bathy_dem_ft] + [pattern]),315,45)`

7. Again you can copy and paste this formula using Notepad.  Copy the formula in and click OK to start the calculation.

What this does is to modify the DEM by adding the new higher values for the trees to the original DEM values, and that is then hillshaded.  All of this is done with this one calculation.

8. The result is a "bump map" which you can see when you turn off the Pattern layer and turn on your Bump Map layer.

---

**Symbolize the bump map**

1. Start with the vegetation layer to color just the areas with trees. Your vegetation layer is called Park Trees which you will now turn on.
2. Right click it to take look at the Properties.
3. On the Symbology tab, set the color to green to show trees, then on the Display tab set the transparency to 80%.
4. Click OK to all of these, then turn on your other flattened raster layer to show how the trees look on top of the land surface that you symbolized earlier.

---

**Extra info**

One can see the tool in this image :

[image: Toolbox]

***Ref. : https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/01/21/introducing-the-arcgis-bump-map-tools/***

---

**Bump map part 1** :

> Part 1 creates the random point pattern(s) based on user defined
>   inputs about how the bumps for the vegetation should appear

The tool simply creates a random pattern of points in the vegetation extent, but the smart part is hidden within the parameters...

---

**Bump map part 2** : creates the surface of bump (cones or domes), overlay it with the DEM, hillshading

One can see the formulae to create to cones in the image countained in the blog post :

[image: Cone generation]

***Ref. :  https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/01/27/a-concise-history-of-bump-mapping/***

Comment: I have asked this question on ESRI Geonet and waiting for help from there.

Comment: Hope you find it !

Comment: Extra ref. here : http://ibis.geog.ubc.ca/courses/geob370/notes/cartography/AdvancedCartographicEffects.pdf (p44)

Comment: You can find : Jeffery S. Nighbert email and phone  at the end of this document : https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f396/b533564b925d958e76aa6b05de00ad9e5036.pdf

Comment: I think availability of these tools will make it easy to get desired results. Otherwise, I am getting hard to interpret how should I produce such results.

Comment: Hope you can find something. I'm afraid the tutorial I copied into my answer is lacking some detailed info to do the job right. I guess some of the answers are in the formulaes but not everything alas.

Comment: Yes exactly this is my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the ArcGIS Bump Map Tools at [ArcGIS Code Sharing](http://codesharing.arcgis.com/) and they are not there.

[image]

Consequently, I think that you should try to contact the author of that blog which is signed:

> Rajinder Nagi, Esri Research Cartographer

Comment: These tools are really hard to find:-) This is nice to contact developer of these tools.

Comment: Much debate about the excellent old ArcScripts website has been going on over on geonet, especially this [thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/182094-please-restore-arcscripts). Jim Barry has uploaded an Excel file listing everything that was on ArcScripts and a simple search on "bump" returns nothing. In the constant restructuring that ESRI do I think they have killed off the link but have not had the wit to move it to the obvious code sharing repository. If you track it down I would very much like to try it as that blog you link to was interesting.

Comment: The result from Bump Map Tools as shown in the referred post are really fascinating for cartographers. The availability of these tools has much potential to present reality. I have uploaded same question over ESRI Geonet anticipating some response from the developer of these tools from the post as well.

Comment: @Hornbydd it was a toolbox listed in a special area appart from the  arcscript area if i recall correctly, that's maybe with it wasn't listed in the Excel listing ? they was a bunch of tools like the SWISS hillshading tools in there. I think it was something like 'Ask a Cartographer"

Comment: It was "ArcGIS Resources-Model & Scripts page of Mapping Center" but that now redirects to https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/category/mapping/

Comment: There is also an [idea](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/12287) worth voting on.

Comment: @Ben I have placed a request for this tool to be resurrected in the [Map Advice area](https://geonet.esri.com/message/709626-can-someone-from-esri-resurrect-the-bump-map-tool) of geonet as apparently that is now the go to place for cartographer questions.

Comment: @Hornbydd I think your comment has just about enough to be an answer that I would upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The ArcGIS Bump Map Tool is indeed up and working; you will need a Spatial Analysis license to use it. See the links above for the download and information on symbolizing the bump map.

For those of you wanting to create a bump map, here's a small sampling of values in order to get a sense of what the values produce. It is a 3-axis plot of values, however the height value has a negligible difference in plan view.

[image]